# How to get clean html from gridmanager.js

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using gridmanager.js for creating dynamic grids in my web application

https://github.com/neokoenig/jQuery-gridmanager/

```
var gm = $("#mycanvas").gridmanager(
    { 
    remoteURL:base_url+'backend/menu/save_customgrid/'+menu_id,
    debug: 1,
    ckeditor: {
    customConfig: base_url+"web/admin/dist/js/example-ckeditor.js"
    } 
   }
   ).data('gridmanager');

$('#save_grid').click(function(){
   gm.cleanup();
   gm.saveremote();
});
```

My problem is,`gm.cleanup();` not clearing the controlls of this plugin.I need to save the html without the html controlls.I need the cleared html .How it is possible?

Comment: Just as a side note, I'm doing a complete rewrite in 0.4 which will make this exact scenario a *lot* easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use   gm.deinitCanvas(); insted of  gm.cleanup();